# Google Hangouts. Start a call with predefined participants

Tags: html, google-hangouts, videochat

I am trying to integrate a little bit interaction into customer support section of my site:
Let's say I have an oncall person A. Customer comes into customer support section of the site and click button which will start a hangout session automatically adding oncall person A. I was looking into https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api however did not see anything that can allow me to accomplish it. Is there any way to do this scenario with Hangouts or should I look for another videoconferencing service? Do you know any alternative?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and little bit playing around with different systems we ended up using WebRTC for that project. This solution had only one drawback since it is not supported by IE, however at this point we decided that it is a best option. Maybe in future WebRTC will be supported in IE as well and this will be no longer an issue or if it will be an issue we will try to find something else.

Answer (score 0):

@Alexanderm

excellent question.

I also seek interaction in random mode

only saw here: `https://www.verbling.com/community`